# c# Searching List<t> inside another List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

How would I search for a value within a `List<t>` inside another `List<t>`

i.e.

```
//FooInner Class
public class FooInner {

  public int FooInnerId { get; set; }
  public String FooValue { get; set; }

}   

//FooOuter Class
public class FooOuter {

  public int FooOuterId { get; set; }
  public List<FooInner> FooInnerCollection { get; set; }

}
```

If I just wanted to find a value in the outer class

```
// Working code

List<FooOuter> fooOuterCollection = GetSomeData(); 

var tmp = fooOuterCollection.Find( f => f.FooOuterId == 2 );
```

But what if I wanted the `FooInner` Object where `FooOuterId == 2` and `FooInnerCollection.FooInnerId == 4` (or contains depending how you look at it).

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: All good answers cheers guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fooOuterCollection
    .Where(outer => outer.FooOuterID == 2)
    .SelectMany(outer => outer.FooInnerCollection)
    .FirstOrDefault(fooInner => fooInner.FooInnerId == 4);
```

First we filter the outer objects to only include those with Id == 2

Then we use SelectMany to flatten out the multiple InnerCollections that we may find

Finally we filter based on the inner Id == 4

Comment: i like that answer as well :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can get inner object like this-

```
var temp=  fooOuterCollection.Where(f => f.FooOuterId == 2)
            .SelectMany(f => f.FooInnerCollection)
            .FirstOrDefault(fi => fi.FooInnerId == 4));
```

If you need outer object, you need to use `Any()` extension method to see if `inner list contains required element` -

```
var temp = fooOuterCollection.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FooOuterId == 2 &&
               f.FooInnerCollection.Any(fi => fi.FooInnerId == 4);
```

Comment: this will return the outer object, not inner

Comment: This is what Im looking for thank you. Actually Alex my question is incorrect not the answer but well spotted. If I have the outer object i can get to the inner one so its not a problem. :-)

Comment: @William - Should i revert back then?

Comment: The text and the code don't really share the same thought. "You need to use Any().." and than providing code without using it, looks kinda strange.

Comment: No that's good. My problem is a little more complicated but those answers give my the correct path to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use LINQ's query syntax:

```
var results = from o in outerList
      where o.FooOuterId == 2
      from i in o.FooInnerCollection
      where i.FooInnerId == 4
      select i;
```

Comment: Will give the right results set but the asker wants a single object so you would need FirstOrDefault() or equivalent